# facing a postgres error while running rake migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rake

I am getting the following uuid error while running a rails app with postgres as backend. Can someone help me out with which dependency is needed.

```
 [root@localhost webapp]# rake db:migrate
    (in /root/mysite/webapp)
    ==  CreateContributors: migrating =============================================
    -- create_table(:contributors, {:id=>false})
       -> 0.0121s
    -- execute("alter table contributors add primary key (id)")
    NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "contributors_pkey" for table "contributors"
       -> 0.0797s
    -- execute("alter table contributors alter column id set default uuid_generate_v1()::varchar")
    rake aborted!
    An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    PGError: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    : alter table contributors alter column id set default uuid_generate_v1()::varchar
```

Answer (score 1):

The `uuid_generate_v1()` function is part of the [uuid-ossp package](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) and you have to install that into PostgreSQL before you can use it. You should have a file called `uuid-ossp.sql` in your PostgreSQL `contrib` directory. You can install the package with:

```
$ psql -d your_database < /the/path/to/uuid-ossp.sql
```

You'll probably want to run that as the database super user.

Comment: thanks it worked now actually path was a problem it was in pgsql/contrib and i was looking in postgres folder

Comment: The directory on ubuntu for this file seems to be:

/usr/share/postgresql/[postgres-version]/extension